# MergedDictionaries nightmare

Tags: c#, wpf, mergeddictionaries

I'm trying to use a WPF Template and I'm supposed to include this in my App.xaml, but I get "Nested properties are not supported: ResourceDictionaries.MergedDictionaries" error and "The attachable property "MergedDictionaries" was not found in type "ResourceDictionary".

```
 <Application x:Class="Unico.App"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

                 StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
        <Application.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

                <!-- Set default skin -->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="\ExpressionDark.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="\WindowStyle.xaml"/>


            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}" />

        </Application.Resources>
    </Application>
```

I've tried everything but still can't fix this. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MergedDictionaries is a property of ResourceDictionary.
Change to:

```
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            ...
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed "The attachable property "MergedDictionaries" was not found in type "ResourceDictionary". But I still get "Nested properties are not supported: ResourceDictionaries.MergedDictionaries" error.

Comment: @Sturm is your code exactly the same as here? this troubles me: "Nested properties are not supported: **ResourceDictionaries**.MergedDictionaries" when the valid property is **ResourceDictionary**.MergedDictionaries. examine also the content of included files.

Comment: That implicit style you've got for the workaround must be within a ResourceDictionary and not in the MergedDictionaries. If you do that, you might need to nest the merged dictionaries one more level by throwing that into another ResourceDictionary.  Ex: App.Resources->ResourceDictionary->Style rectangle & ResourceDictionary->ResourceDictionary.MergedDict->here you put your merged xaml.

Comment: @Erode look closer at my xaml - Style for Rectangle is not in MergedDictionaries.

Comment: @lisp Ah, I'm sorry, that is what I get for trying to use Stackoverflow on my phone.